What numbers have the same bitwise representation in IEEE-754 binary64 (“double precision”) and 64-bit two’s complement long
Are there any values for which the 64-bit two’s complement representation (sometimes used for long) and the IEEE-754 binary64 representation (often used for double) are the same? If so, how many such numbers exist and what are they? Does anyone know of any research or discussions on this topic?
I found just 0, for which bitwise representation in double and long are equal, for both it will be just 64 bits of zeros. Is there any other? If we take 1, then bitwise representation of long 1 using two's complement is 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001, and for double is 0 01111111111 0000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000. Hence they are not identical in bitwise representation.

A 64-bit two’s complement represents integers in [−263, +263). Obviously −263 does not have the same representation in both, so we reduce the candidates to (−263, +263) and exclude zero, which we know does have the same representation. To represent a magnitude less than 263, the binary64 format uses an exponent from 0 to 62. These correspond to 1023-biased exponent encodings from 1023 to 1085. The biased exponent field is in bits 62-52. All the biased exponents from 1023 to 1085 have bit 61 set. So, for positive numbers, the two’s complement form must represent a number that is at least 261, so candidates under 261 are eliminated. We will consider positive numbers first and then return to negative numbers.
A binary64 number has at most 53 significand bits, and any number 261 or greater uses at least 62 bits in unsigned binary, so the low nine integer bits of any represented number 261 or greater must be zero. So the two’s complement representation has zeros in bits 8-0.
Bit i in the trailing significand field of a binary64 with exponent e corresponds to 2i-52+e in the represented value. So, if bits 8-0 are zero in the trailing significand field of a binary64 with exponent 61, then bits 8−52+61 = 17 to 0−52+61 = 9 must be zero in the two’s complement representation. And since 17-9 are zero, 26-18 must zero, and so must 35-27, 44-36, and 51-45, which exhausts the bits in the trailing significand field.
If the exponent is 62, then the low ten bits must be zero, so bits 9-0 are zero. If bit i is zero, then bit i−52+62 = i+10 must be zero, so bits 19-10 are zero, and so are 29-20, 39-30, 49-40, and 51-50.
This leaves only numbers with the trailing significand field completely zero, leaving only candidates that are powers of 2, so 261 and 262. Those do not have the same representations in 64-bit two’s complement and binary64, so there are no positive numbers with the same representation.
For negative numbers, note the biased exponent 1023 corresponds to exponent 0, for which the only representable integer is −1=−20 (as −2=−21 has exponent 1), and so there is no match with this biased exponent. The other candidates, 1024 to 1085, all have the 512 bit of the biased exponent clear. This is bit 61 of the binary64 format. So all represented values are at least 261 in magnitude. Again, with exponent 61, the low nine integer bits, bits 8-0, must be zero. The same reasoning as above applies, bits 17-9 are zero, and so on. Exponent 62 proceeds similarly. This exhausts the candidates. Other than zero, no binary64 has the same representation as its 64-bit two’s complement.

If we cheat slightly, we could add 4886674138783273204 and
-4337501956902952561 to 0 as a solution:
int main() {
    long x = 4886674138783273204;
    double xf = x;
    unsigned long xfl;
    memcpy(&xfl, &xf, sizeof xfl);
    printf("%ld\n%ld\n", x, xfl);
}

This prints twice 4886674138783273204. (The cheat is in that this conversion isn't exact, if I convert xf back to long I get 4886674138783272960.)
I searched using z3, and there is no other solutions:
from z3 import *

x_bv = BitVec('b', 64)
x_fp_pattern = z3.fpBVToFP(x_bv, z3.Float64())
x_fp_value = z3.fpSignedToFP(RTZ(), x_bv, z3.Float64())
s = Solver()
s.add(x_fp_value == x_fp_pattern)

while s.check() == sat:
    val = s.model()[x_bv].as_signed_long()
    print(val)
    s.add(x_bv != val)


Here is a second answer using a different technique.
We know zero is one solution and consider others.
Consider functions b(x) mapping a 64-bit unsigned binary numeral x to the 64-bit two’s complement number it represents and f(x) mapping x to the IEEE-754 binary64 number it represents.
The binary64 representation is increasing for positive numbers and decreasing for negative numbers, so f(x) increases for 0 ≤ x < 263 and decreases for 263 ≤ x < 264. Further the amount of the increase increases as the exponent encoded in x increases (the same direction that x increases). And b(x) increases by exactly 1 for each unit increment of x except for the discontinuity at 263.
So, in 0 ≤ x < 263, b(x) is a straight line with a 45º slope, and f(x) is curved upward, starting shallow (a change in x yields a very small increase in f(x)) and increasing. In this interval, these functions intersect in at most one point other than x = 0.
In 263 ≤ x < 264, b(x) is again a straight line at 45º and f(x) curves downward. These also intersect in at most one point.
Thus, we can simply do a binary search between candidate endpoints in these intervals. The following code does that and reports there are no solutions. It also reports the points straddling the intersection of the functions.
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


//  Return return the 64-bit two’s complement value represented by x.
static int64_t b(uint64_t x)
{
    return (union { uint64_t u; int64_t i; }) {x} .i;
}


//  Return return the binary64 value represented by x.
static double f(uint64_t x)
{
    return (union { uint64_t u; double d; }) {x} .d;
}


/*  Return -1, 0, or +1 according to whether b(x) is less than, equal to, or
    greater than f(x).  f(x) is assumed to be in [-2^63, +2^63).  Every such
    f(x) can be converted to int64_t with no rounding error other than
    truncation of the fraction.
*/
static int s(uint64_t x)
{
    int64_t bv = b(x);
    double  fv = f(x);

    //  Compare the integer parts.
    int64_t fi = fv;
    if (bv < fi)
        return -1;
    else if (fi < bv)
        return +1;

    /*  The compared values are equal, but comparison truncates the fraction
        portion of a floating-point value.  So we test that.  If the fraction
        is negative, fv is actually less than bv, and so on.
    */
    double t = fv - fi;

    if (t < 0)
        return -1;
    else if (0 < t)
        return +1;

    return 0;
}


static void Report(uint64_t x)
{
    printf("Found bits 0x%" PRIx64 " represent %" PRId64 " and %.99g.\n",
        x, b(x), f(x));
}


//  Seek a solution for b(x) = f(x) with low <= x <= high.
static void Search(uint64_t low, uint64_t high)
{
    printf("Searching from 0x%" PRIx64 " to 0x%" PRIx64 ".\n", low, high);
    //  Record the signs of the endpoints.
    int ls = s(low);
    int hs = s(high);

    //  Check endpoints.
    if (ls == 0) { Report(low ); return; }
    if (hs == 0) { Report(high); return; }

    //  Verify low and high are on opposite sides of the transition.
    if (ls == hs)
    {
        printf("Error, low 0x%" PRIx64 " and high 0x%" PRIx64 " have same sign for s.\n",
            low, high);
        return;
    }

    //  Do a binary search.
    while (1)
    {
        uint64_t t = low + (high-low) / 2;

        //  When (high-low) / 2 is zero, we are done.
        if (t == low)
        {
            printf("No solution, intersection bounded by:\n");
            printf("\tBits 0x%" PRIx64 " representing %" PRId64 " and %.99g.\n",
                low,  b(low ), f(low ));
            printf("\tBits 0x%" PRIx64 " representing %" PRId64 " and %.99g.\n",
                high, b(high), f(high));
            return;
        }

        int ts = s(t);
        if (ts == 0) { Report(t); return; }

        if (ts == ls)
            low  = t;
        else
            high = t;
    };
}


//  Return the binary64 encoding of x.
static uint64_t u(double x)
{
    return (union { double d; uint64_t u; }) {x} .u;
}


int main(void)
{
    /*  Search from 1 to the value representing the last representable value
        before 2^63.
    */
    Search(1, nexttoward(u(+0x1p63), 0));

    //  Search from the value representing -1 to the value representing -2^63.
    Search(u(-1), u(-0x1p63));
}

The output is:

Searching from 0x1 to 0x43dffffffffffc00.
No solution, intersection bounded by:
    Bits 0x43d0f43d0f43d0f4 representing 4886674138783273204 and 4886674138783272960.
    Bits 0x43d0f43d0f43d0f5 representing 4886674138783273205 and 4886674138783273984.
Searching from 0xbff0000000000000 to 0xc3e0000000000000.
No solution, intersection bounded by:
    Bits 0xc3ce18f3863ce18f representing -4337501956902952561 and -4337501956902952448.
    Bits 0xc3ce18f3863ce190 representing -4337501956902952560 and -4337501956902952960.


TLDR: No, only 0 has the same bitwise representation between long and double.
This basically comes down to long and double being two data types with different encoding schemes.
long uses two's complement system while Double uses IEEE 754 format.
This means that long is composed by 1 bit for the sign and the remaining 63 bits represent the magnitude of the integer in binary.
On the other hand, double uses 1 bit for the sign, 11 bits for the exponent and 52 bits for the fraction.

Note: You can actually do an exhaustive scan, at least for 32 bit. Here is the code https://godbolt.org/z/YEv8EdP1K It returns 0, 1318926965, and -834214802. However, the other two matches cannot be accurately represented by float so I'm not sure they should count.

Your description of long is closer to a description of sign/magnitude rather than two's complement. If you're claiming that 63 bits are for magnitude, why is it that -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and 0 have the same values in the magnitude section? Or why do 1 and -1 have 63 bits set differently?

@Damien_The_Unbeliever I wanted to address the OP question "Is there any other number that has the same representation" without going too deep into the encoding specifics, at the end of the day, the reason is that long and double just use different encodings. But yeah, MSB will differ if the number is positive/negative and the bits will be flipped if the number is negative.

Two numbers with different encoding schemes might happen to have some values in common, though. 8-bit one's complement and 8-bit sign-magnitude, for instance, coincidentally both encode -64 as 0b11000000.
